# Cartesian product of a family of sets by halmos

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

can someone please give me an example for this sentence, (i don't want a formal definition) thank's.

Comment: **Please** use proper words, and not internet abbreviations. You're not paying your service provider by the letter you type. And if you do, it's a scam, find a better provider.

Comment: In the duplicate there are three linked questions, read them also.

Comment: @AsafKaragila those explanations didn't help, what i want is an example of the statement above that would be nice if it was included in the book itself.

Comment: I can't go back in time and edit the book. Is the example given by See-Woo Lee below not enough? It's hard and nearly impossible to give "complicated examples". So you'll have to make do with the simple ones. And learn how to work with the formal definition, one step at a time (as one should do, anyway). Please clarify what's missing exactly.

Comment: the problem is that the book is about "naive set theory", so "formalism" is not supposed to be used. Am'I missing something?

Comment: Yes. Mathematics, even "naive" *should* be rigorous and work with the definitions. You can wave your hands as much as you'd like, but at the end of the day proofs should come from definitions, not from examples. I am not a huge fan of Halmos' book, and I'd recommend Enderton's book for learning basic set theory.

Comment: The example is just to understand the definition, the examples i see in all the previous threads are not derived from the sentence in Halmos book, they are examples of the general definition of cartesian product. I wish somebody explains to me this particular sentence by an example written specifically for it.

Comment: Well, a tuple is just a function. Look at the answer you already have here, and tell me what's missing.

Comment: I completely understand the example of @See-Woo Lee, the problem is: how is it related to the definition given by Halmos?

Comment: An $n$-tuple is a function with domain $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. So $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ such that $x_i\in X_i$ is *exactly* an element of the product. It might be worth to clarify here, as well, that a "family" is just a tuple in this context, it is a function with domain $I$, or in this case, $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. (Let e remark that traditionally, $n$ tuples would be indexed by $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, but this is the same thing of course.)

Answer (score 1):

For a finite set $I=\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, Cartesian product of $X_{i}$'s is 
\begin{align}
\{(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n})|x_{i}\in X_{i}\}
\end{align}
For example, $\mathbb{R}^{2}$- Euclidean plane - is Cartesian product of two $\mathbb{R}$'s. We can choose $I$ as infinite set. The set of sequence of real numbers 
\begin{align}
\{(a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, \dots)|a_{i}\in \mathbb{R}\,\,\forall i\in \mathbb{N}\}
\end{align}
is Cartesian product of infinitely (countably) many $i$'s. We can even define Cartesian product for uncountable set $I$. Let $I=\mathbb{R}$ and $X_{r}=\mathbb{R}$ for each $r\in I=\mathbb{R}$. Then Cartesian product of $X_{r}$'s (usually denoted by $\prod_{r\in I}X_{r}$) is same as set of functions 
\begin{align}
\{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\}.
\end{align}